# E: Unable to locate package cvc5

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, cvc4

I'm new to SMT solvers software and would like to ask for some help installing it.
On Ubuntu for Windows, it throws 'Unable to locate package cvc5' error. What could be done to solve this?

/home$ **sudo apt install cvc5**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cvc5

/home$ **sudo apt-get install cvc5**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cvc5

/home$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    **Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS**
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply getting the binary from https://cvc5.github.io/downloads.html might be the easiest way to go, instead of trying to build it from scratch.

If you need to compile it yourself (don't do this unless you really need to!), follow the instructions on https://cvc5.github.io/docs/cvc5-1.0.2/installation/installation.html and let us know if you run into issues.